# Design challenge for a job interview

Tags: website-design

The task says to identify potential user issues on a website's page and to suggest an approach to test these potential issues. They also want me to **outline my process/es for addressing these issues**. I don't really know what it means to "address" the issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Get comfortable with asking your stakeholders clarifying questions. Call them back and ask them what they mean by "address", because it's definitely unclear. If they don't want to answer your question, you don't want to work there.

Comment: To fix them so they aren't issues anymore.

Comment: They just want you to make clear what you think should be done to resolve the issues.

Comment: Beware of these kinds of companies that offer designers situational design challenges to keep them for their own good. Many designers fell into these situations where they got rejected after spending hours doing a design challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing these issues means resolving these issues.
They are asking you to detail your process and propose solutions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like they would like to see your process in identifying,  tackling and proposing solutions for a website with clear issues but not telling you what they are. I suspect that this is coming from the classic client problem of they know something is wrong but they don't know what.

This is how I would approach something like this, and Im not saying that this is the right answer, I'm just speaking from my own similar experiences:

> The task says to identify potential user issues on a website's page
> and to suggest an approach to test these potential issues.

You're not going to understand these what 'issues' are until you have some answered questions:

- What are the goals of the website page for the user and for the business?
- Are there any existing issues that they know of?
- Who are their core users / audience?
- What do they want to learn about this page?
- What questions do they want to ask users?

You could probably spot blindingly obvious usability and visual design issues based on common sense and your professional opinion. But to dig deeper in to any analysis or find deeper issues **I would be asking questions for clarification and direction**.

I would **push for answers to your questions**. If they don't want to answer them I would be asking why and pushing for them. And if they're still not budging, I would question why you're doing the task at all as any stakeholder would answer these to get the best possible solutions to problems.

It also sounds like they want to test it in some form.

> They also want me to outline my process/es for addressing these
> issues. I don't really know what it means to "address" the issues. Any
> ideas?

This sounds like they want to you take what you learn from speaking to people and what you would do to solve any of the learnings and recommendations you find out. But I would point blank ask them to clarify and define "address the issues".

In all it sounds like they want you to find out what the issues are with the page and what your recommendations would be to fix said issues. But this is an assumption, **there is nothing wrong with seeking clarity and if they don't want to give it, I would be questioning if you should be working there at all.**

Like with any design task for jobs though, they all have different expectations from it. And I would ask questions as much as possible to get answers.